# how to Get user's email friend list by using Google People API and with APIs Explorer

Tags: list, email, google-api, google-apis-explorer, contact-list

[This is a snapshot of Google API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTqrp.png)

I tried several parameters but did not work. Please help me what is the query parameter and where I should include it? I tried several times but still have the issue. I have no clue to do this. I have studied Google API document and Google API Explorer document too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.